# Revit API External Command freezing after WinForms Close() event

Tags: c#, winforms, api, revit

I am trying to create an external command for Revit that pops up a windows forms that has a single text box for the user to enter a description. After the user clicks Ok, the form closes but Revit gets stuck in a loading motion. It doesn't freeze, it just is constantly loading something. When I pause debugging, the code only made it to the line form.ShowDialog(). If I take out the showdialog and just run it without the form, it runs fine.

I'll post my relevant code snippets below. The form is in its own .cs, separate from the external command .cs but still under the same namespace.

Form click events code:

```
private void CancelForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isReport = false;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    Close();
}

private void SubmitForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    isReport = true;
    reportDesc = descriptionBox.Text;
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

Execute command:

```
    public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        //Get application and document objects
        UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
        Document doc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
        ReportForm ticket = new ReportForm();
        ticket.ShowDialog();
```

The code stops processing after showdialog. From what I could read on it, I thought it might have to do with focus on Revit after the form closing or the form not closing properly but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just wanted to add that I had it under a try/catch and did not receive any errors for any part of the script. It doesn't fail, it just won't move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old sample that creates a minimal Windows form on the fly, displays it as a modal form and closes successfully afterwards: [The Schedule API and Access to Schedule Data](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/05/the-schedule-api-and-access-to-schedule-data.html). Maybe that will help. Maybe the debugger is interfering with the form closing somehow?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy for responding. Maybe I was missing something but there wasn't a closing event for the form or any code after it in the link you provided. I have looked through several of your posts including the ones about Revit requiring focus and thought my problem might lie there but honestly I have no clue anymore.

Comment: The click events are working, I am assuming since the form will close after I click the Ok button. And it looks like Revit starts loading right after the event but I have no idea what Revit is trying to do after the form closes.

Comment: If you just leave the Windows form to do its thing with no further interference, it closes all by itself. In programming, it is mostly easiest to follow the flow, not fight against it. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!

Comment: Could you explain it a bit more? I thought the form was simple as is. It is just a textbox with an OK button. All I need from it is whatever the user types in the textbox for something later on in the script. For the form, the only event it has is to close the form.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up remaking the entire addin, made sure I was using Jeremy Tammik's Revit Addin Wizard to initiate it, and it started working. Not exactly sure what fixed it but guessing it was some error in the set up or such.